# How do I enter ID messages in the database?

Tags: mongodb, discord.py

Good time of day! I want to enter the bot's id messages in the database, but I can't do it, there are no errors

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

cluster = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://******:******@cluster0.tssju.mongodb.net/mpdb?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
collection = cluster.mpdb.mpmp


@commands.command(aliases = ["мероприятие"])  # Прекратите. Насиловать. Труп.
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def mp(self, ctx):  # self если мы находимся в модуле или подклассе Bot'а
    embed = discord.Embed(title="228")
    msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await msg.add_reaction('✅')
    post = {"_id": msg}
    collection.insert_one(post)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to be only setting the id which is int64 in Mongo. To find it you simply execute: `collection.find_one({"msg_id": msg.id})` as it's stored under the key `msg_id`

```py
from pymongo import MongoClient

cluster = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://******:******@cluster0.tssju.mongodb.net/mpdb?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
collection = cluster.mpdb.mpmp


@commands.command(aliases = ["мероприятие"])  # Прекратите. Насиловать. Труп.
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def mp(self, ctx):  # self если мы находимся в модуле или подклассе Bot'а
    embed = discord.Embed(title="228")
    msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await msg.add_reaction('✅')
    collection.insert_one({"msg_id": msg.id})
```

Comment: Still doesn't write the message id to the database

Comment: @negativegto have a look at connecting and authentication to a pymongo database, make sure your IP is allowed. It works for me.